# What are the differences between a Weretiger's animal and hybrid forms?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, lycanthropy

I'm currently making a weretiger character in D&D 3.5 and was wondering what all the listed differences are between its animal and hybrid forms. I don't need anything that would be considered cosmetic. He's an inherited weretiger with the base race of human.

(Having seen D20 SRD's entry its layout is focused more on the individual aspects of the template in general and less on the individual alternate forms. I think I've gotten most of the differences noted, but I just want to be sure.)

Comment: What aspects of the Weretiger are confusing? http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/lycanthrope.htm#weretiger seems to be a pretty good explanation...

Answer (score 3):

This probably requires just a list of what is different, so here what applies to a human/tiger lycanthrope:

- While you are Large Humanoid (Human, Shapechanger) in both forms you are large-long in animal form of a tiger and large-tall in hybrid form. Tiger looks like a regular tiger, and hybrid is antropomorphic tiger standing on it's hind legs.
- Speed. You have tiger's speed in animal form. You have human's speed in hybrid form.
- If you have somehow managed to increase human's natural armor to the amount greater than natural armor a tiger has (a humble +3), hybrid will use the better value. This is highly unlikely, though.
- Based of the fact you are long or tall depending on form, your natural reach, as well as vertical reach probably, is different for those forms. By default it's 5' for tiger and 10' for hybrid.
- You only have animal's Special Attacks if you are in animal form, so no Improved Grab, Rake and Pounce for the hybrid. Also, as it is mentioned under special attacks, tiger form isn't capable of speech and fine manipulation. Hybrid is capable of last while still incapable of former.
- "Conditional skill bonuses only apply in the associated form", so your racial bonus to hide skill will be different in areas of tall grass or heavy undergrowth. +8 in tiger form and only +4 in hybrid form.

As you can see there isn't many of them and they are readily available from statblocks and a template description. As far as a I can tell there isn't anything in the rules stealthily influensing human weretiger as well as natural lycanthropies in general.